# JSON to PHP array getting "Trying to get property of non-object in" Error

Tags: php, json

Hello I have Json like this:

```
[{
    "exam_code": "1",
    "name": "Name1",
    "surname": "Surname1",
    "father_name": "Fname1",
    "id_number": "211111",
    "district_number": "21",
    "school_number": "025",
    "gender": "F",
    "variant": "A",
    "grade": "4",
    "sector": "A",
    "foreign_language": "I",
    "answerList": {
        "gradeFour": {
            "lesson1": ["A", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", " ", "C", "C", "B", "A", "C", "C", "B", "B", "C", "B", "A"],
            "lesson2": ["B", "A", " ", "C", " ", "B", " ", "B", "B", "C", " ", " ", "B", "A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "B", "B"],
            "lesson3": ["A", "C", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "A", "C", "C"],
            "lesson4": ["B", "B", "A", "B", "B"],
            "lesson5": ["B", "A", "A", "B", "B"],
            "lesson6": ["B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B"]
        }
    }
}]
```

I am trying to print out lessons answers on foreach loop.

tried below code:

```
<?php
$msc = microtime(true);


$array = (json_decode($raw_str,true));

foreach($array as $value){
echo $value['id_number'];
    echo '<br/>';

   foreach($value -> answerList->gradeFour as $val){
        echo $val;    
  }

  echo '<br>---------------------------';
  echo '<br>';

}
$msc = microtime(true)-$msc;
echo ($msc * 1000) . ' ms'; // in millseconds
?>
```

But getting this error

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   G:\xampp\htdocs\siec\string_test.php on line 50 Notice: Trying to get
>   property of non-object in G:\xampp\htdocs\siec\string_test.php on line
>   50 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   G:\xampp\htdocs\siec\string_test.php on line 50

Comment: You start using `$value['id_number']` and then switch to object notation access(`$value -> answerList`), you can use one or the other (depending on the second argument to `json_decode()`) but can't mix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems to your code:

- First, you have to use brackets instead of ->
- Second, you need to use nested loop (two fors) to print the grades, since you have multiple grades (an array) for multiple lessons (another array).

So your complete code will be like this:

```
$msc = microtime(true);

$array = (json_decode($raw_str,true));

foreach($array as $value){
echo $value['id_number'];
    echo '<br/>';

   foreach($value['answerList']['gradeFour'] as $course){
        foreach($course as $val){
            echo $val;    
        }   
    }

  echo '<br>---------------------------';
  echo '<br>';

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply... Solved

Comment: @fischer Great. You can accept the answer, as a guide for next visitors.

Comment: is it possible to use foreach($value['answerList']['gradeFour'] as $course){    as foreach($value['answerList'][0] as $course){   because gradefour gradefive it dynamic

Comment: @fischer No, you cant use numbers to access a named array. However, you can iterate on `answerList` too. like `foreach($value['answerList'] as $numberCourses){` and the iterate on $numberCourses to get $course, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In your second `foreach` loop, `$value` is an array. So you have to use it with brackets `[]` not `->` :

```
foreach($value['answerList']['gradeFour'] as $val) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in line 5
you must decode it as associative arrays
read [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

check the code below, it will help you to more understand

```
 $array = json_decode($raw_str);

 foreach($array as $value){
    echo $value->id_number;
    echo '<br/>';

    foreach($value->answerList->gradeFour as $key => $val){
       echo $key;
       echo "<pre>";
       print_r($val);
       echo "</pre>";

    }

    echo '<br>---------------------------';
    echo '<br>';

}
```

Comment: This approach adds too much change to the original code: this had to change the way he fetches `id_number`, and the way he converts from json. Original code obviously wanted array as the result of `json_decode`, so it is wrong to convert other parts of the code. Also, this answer is simply dumping the whole array of grades and he added `pre` tag when it is not been asked.